# Min/Max values for Apple Watch Accelerometer

Tags: ios, accelerometer, apple-watch, core-motion

On Apple Watch `CMMotionManager` returns acceleration for x,y,z in **+/-16G** range.

I can easily replicate with same motion the same max acceleration (absolutely same numbers):
x = -15.959534, y = -16.145355, z = 16.158539

Is there any way to take greater accelerations? Does apple say anywhere about accelerometer limitations/precision? What motions sensor model is used in Apple Watch?

**UPDATE:**
In Apple Watch Series 4 accelerometer should allow **32G**